# key word args to dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

is there a way to make all of the keys and values or items to a single dictionary?

```
 def file_lines( **kwargs):
        for key, username in kwargs.items():
            convert_to_string = str(len(username))
            #a = key +":"+ convert_to_string
            dict = {}
            v = dict[key]= convert_to_string
            print(dict)
    file_lines(
          F1 = "C://downloads/Anime",
          F2 = "C://downloads/Manga",
          F3 = "C://downloads/Music",
          F4 = "C://downloads/Images")
```

the answer I get after running the code above:

> {'F1': '19'}
> {'F2': '19'}
> {'F3': '19'}
> {'F4': '20'}

Comment: `**kwargs` IS a dictionary. What do you expect to get?

Comment: yes, but i wanted the answer to be like this: {F1: 19, F2:19, F3:20, F4:20} is there a possible way to do that

Comment: The reason your output isn't as you expect is you are creating a fresh `dict` within your loop. Move `dict = {}` outside your loop and it should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
def file_lines( **kwargs):
        dict = {}
        for key, username in kwargs.items():
            dict[key]= str(len(username))
        print(dict)

file_lines(
          F1 = "C://downloads/Anime",
          F2 = "C://downloads/Manga",
          F3 = "C://downloads/Music",
          F4 = "C://downloads/Images")
```

Your mistake is that you initialize `dict` inside the loop...

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
def file_lines( **kwargs):
    temp= {}
    for key, username in kwargs.items():
        convert_to_string = str(len(username))
        temp[key]= convert_to_string
    return temp
```

OUTPUT:

```
file_lines(
      F1 = "C://downloads/Anime",
      F2 = "C://downloads/Manga",
      F3 = "C://downloads/Music",
      F4 = "C://downloads/Images")

{'F1': '19', 'F2': '19', 'F3': '19', 'F4': '20'}
```

Comment: Don't use `dict` as a variable name - it shadows the built-in [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) type.

Comment: I just edited @johnmelvin esguerra code. Well I've edited my answer

Comment: thankyou very much, i've been putting the dict = { } inside the for loop the whole time, and yes i will remeber that